# Spawning waves of enemies Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a game in which I want to spawn waves of enemies. In each wave of enemies, I spawn from a different Spawn Point. For exemple, I have 6 Spawn Points, the first wave of enemies spawn from the 4th point, the second wave spawns from the 1st point, etc.

I wrote a code that let me spawn waves of enemies but my problem is that it spawn the waves of enemies from all the 6 spawn points in the first wave of enemies.

When i click on play, I have waves of enemies from the 6 spawn points not from one spawn point for each wave.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Waves : MonoBehaviour
 {
 public GameObject Enemy = null;

 public int hazardCount = 3;
 public float spawnWait=0.5f;
 public float startWait=1;
 public float waveWait=4;            
 public Transform[] spawnPoints; 

 void Start ()
 {
     StartCoroutine(SpawnWaves ());
 }

 IEnumerator SpawnWaves ()
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (startWait);
     while (true)
     {
         for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++)
         {
             int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);

             Instantiate (Enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);

             yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait);
         }
         yield return new WaitForSeconds (waveWait);
     }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since spawnPointIndex is picked inside the loop it picks a new random spawnpoint for each hazard in the wave. If you want it to use the same spawnpoint then pick the spawnPointIndex outside of the hazards loop but inside the waves while(true) loop:

```
 IEnumerator SpawnWaves ()
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds (startWait);
     while (true)
     {
         // Only pick a new spawn point once per wave
         int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);

         for (int i = 0; i < hazardCount; i++)
         {
             // here would pick a new spawn point for each new enemy
             Instantiate (Enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);

             yield return new WaitForSeconds (spawnWait);
         }
         yield return new WaitForSeconds (waveWait);
     }
 }
```

Also consider pulling the enemies from an object pool rather than instantiate new ones each time. It will be much more efficient. See http://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/object-pooling